# Not setting instance variables correctly

Tags: python, class, instance

Somehow I am not able to set instance values for a class instance.
I create multiple instances of a specific class object, but when printing it, I always get the last input, so it seems like I am overwriting the class level values all the time?

```
class newCharacter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = attributes #attributes is set globally as a dictionary with key value pairs
    
    def __str__(self):
        Name = str(self.att["Name"])
        return f"{Name}"
    def inputAttributes(self):  
        print(f"\nDefine Name:")
        self.att["Name"] = str(input())
        #the function continues to go though updating individual dictionary items, i cut that part out here


    def printAttributes(self):
        for k, v in self.att.items():
            print(f"{k}: {v}")
        print("\n")
```

Then I call these

```
a = character.newCharacter()
a.inputAttributes()
a.printAttributes() #code not show


b = character.newCharacter()
b.inputAttributes()
a.printAttributes()
b.printAttributes()
```

There must be a very simple answer to this, but somehow I dont see or find it...
Appreciate your help!

I want to instances with differently updated dictionaries in the end.
I tried to initialize the class different, but cant figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: A comment states that `attributes` is a global dictionary.  Assigning that to `self.att` doesn't make a copy, so every instance shares the same dictionary.  That defeats the usual purpose of having an instance attribute; if you *wanted* the value to be shared, you'd normally assign it in the class body, rather than in `__init__()`.

Comment: Assuming `self.att["Name"]` is already a string, you just need `def __str__(self): return self.att["Name"]`. No need to call `str` or use an f-string to convert one string after another into an identical string.

Comment: ah! that makes sense! I did not realize that it is handing over a reference and not the actual values.... I will change it so the inputAttributes function will add to the dictionary and create that empty in the init

Answer (score 1):

Python's assignment does not copy. This avoids potentially expensive memory operations on compound objects like your global `dict attributes`. So it will only create a reference to `attributes` and let any instance of `newCharacter` operate on this one global dictionary. For immutable operations, that's what you want. In your case, not so much.

To make python create a deep copy, use the `copy` module like this:

```py
import copy

class newCharacter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = copy.deepcopy(attributes)
```

Also take a look at the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

Comment: "Python avoids potentially expensive copy operations of compound objects " - Python actually never copies *anything* when you give it a new name, see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Thanks! I did not know this, makes all sense now...

Comment: Also the deepcopy is very helpful to know!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille +1. `a = b` (AKA "binding"/"rebinding") simply means "make 'a' point at the same thing that 'b' is pointing at."

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thank you for your comment and the link. I changed my introductory sentence to account for the general case.

Answer (score -1):

Keep attribute like name inside the instance object, otherwise you overwrite the value. This is the goal of OOP keep the attributes at the object. You can call it from outside as long as you not define it privat `__attributes`.

```
#global attributes
#attributes = {}

class newCharacter:
    def __init__(self):
        attributes = {}
        self.att = attributes #attributes must be local not global
    
    def __str__(self):
        Name = str(self.att["Name"])
        return f"{Name}"
    def inputAttributes(self):  
        print(f"\nDefine Name:")
        self.att["Name"] = str(input())
        #the function continues to go though updating individual dictionary items, i cut that part out here


    def printAttributes(self):
        for k, v in self.att.items():
            print(f"{k}: {v}")
        print("\n")
        
        
a = newCharacter()
a.inputAttributes()
a.printAttributes()


b = newCharacter()
b.inputAttributes()
a.printAttributes()
b.printAttributes()
```

Output:

```
Define Name:
Paul
Name: Paul



Define Name:
Hugo
Name: Paul


Name: Hugo
```

Comment: thanks! yes, I got i now. Was exactly as simple answer as I thought it will be...